# Policykit issue after installing custom kernel

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, compiling, policykit

OS: Xubuntu
Original Kernel version: 4.4.0
New Kernel version: 4.1.3

I recently compiled a patched kernel. The details of the patch and installation procedure are here: https://wiki.litmus-rt.org/litmus/InstallationInstructions

It's a real-time patch for linux kernel 4.1.3. After patching, I installed the kernel on Xubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.4.0. After installing the patched kernel, there seems to be an issue with the Policy Kit.

Complete `/var/log/syslog` of a boot here: http://pastebin.com/DbLxMpW7

Trying to start polkit

[image]

dbus:

[image]

**Issues:**

Doesn't let me install softwares

[image]

Doesn't automatically mount disks without root permission

[image]

Asks for password for log out/shutdown

[image]

When I boot from the original Xubuntu kernel, all of these issues dissapear. Have I done anything wrong during kernel compilation? Was there some option in `make menuconfig` that was wrongly set?

I don't suspect it's the problem arising from the patch, since, I downloaded the VM Image supplied here: http://www.litmus-rt.org/tutorial/vm-setup.html which had the patch already installed and there none of these issues present.

Answer (score 0):

If your packages are all up to date, you can try an old bug fix for this assuming you're using lightdm.

Edit the file `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

At the bottom, add

```
session required pam_loginuid.so
session required pam_systemd.so
```

This works in some 14.04 distros.  If not, the alternative that has also worked for some is to remove apparmor:

`sudo apt-get remove apparmor -y`

But that's only a solution if you don't depend on apparmor for security.

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately, neither of them worked for me.